# Cloning Rails project and running it on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I cloned a Rails project from Github and I'm trying to run it locally. I keep getting the PG::ConnectionBad error. What changes do I need to make to the database.yml file? And what commands do I need to run afterwards?

Comment: That depends completely on what your local setup is.

Comment: I am using a Ruby devkit that I installed with Rubyinstaller.org

Comment: No what your local postgres setup is.

Comment: I have postgres 12 installed. Is there configuration that I need to do?

Comment: Postgres 12 tells us absolutely nothing about how your database is configured. It's like asking "I have Windows 10 installed. What username and password should I use to login?". If you used an installer to install postgres you need to consult the documentation for the installer and see what credentials it has set up.